# jquery to javascript converted but not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

my initial code was in jquery + ajax and i tried to write it in javascript but its not working now. Can anyone tell me where's the mistake and why its not showing anything when i run through the server? i checked in the console and there is no error either

my code in JQ

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    findteacher = function() {
        var file = "course.php?course="+ $("#course").val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : file,
            datatype : "text",
            success : function(response) {
                var file2 = response.split(",");
                $("#courseInfo").html("The course: " + file2[0] + " Taught by: " + file2[1]);
            }
        });
    }

    clear = function() {
        $("#courseInfo").html("");
    };

    $("#course").click(clear);
    $("#go").click(findteacher);
});
```

My code in JS

```
function findteacher () {

    var file = "course.php" + document.getElementById('course');

    function callAjax(){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('courseInfo').innerHTML =   xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", file, true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);

        var file2 = callAjax.split(",");
        document.getElementById('courseInfo').text("The course: " + file2[0] + " Taught by: " + file2[1]);
    }
    document.getElementById('go').onclick(findteacher)
}   
window.onload = findteacher;
```

Comment: ok its fixed but now i get this in the console `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: That means you've created in infinite recursion.

Comment: My guess is you're calling `findteacher()` inside `findteacher`.

Comment: works perfectly!!! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `?course=` in file. You're not getting `.value` of the course element. `callAjax.split(",")` makes no sense -- `callAjax` is a function, not a string -- you should be using `xmlhttp.responseText.split(",")` in the onreadystatechange function. `onclick` is a property you assign to, not a method, so `.onclick(findteacher)` should be `onclick = findteacher`; and you shouldn't do this inside the function, it should be done just once when the page is loaded.

```
function findteacher () {

    var file = "course.php?course=" + document.getElementById('course').value;

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            var file2 = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
            document.getElementById('courseInfo').innerHTML = "The course: " + file2[0] + " Taught by: " + file2[1];
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", file, true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}   

function clear () {
    document.getElementById('courseInfo').innerHTML = '';
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('go').onclick = findteacher;
    document.getElementById('course').onclick = clear;
}
```

Comment: sir, you are a genius! thank you so much! btw there is a typo on funtion clear()